# Can't fix timestamp of WebM video with dynamic resolution using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, kurento, webm

I'm developing the platform for 1-1 video calls with recording. For my purposes, I work with the following stack: WebRTC, Kurento Media Server, FFmpeg.

1. It works perfectly in an ideal environment, but if my users have a poor connection, after the recording I see a lot of problems with the out of sync audio and video tracks.

   As I understand, the problem appears due to the incorrect timestamp, so I'm doing a bit post-processing where I generate a new timestamp and it helps!

   Here is the command example:

   ```
   ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -acodec libopus -vcodec libvpx \
       -i in.webm \
       -filter_complex "fps=30, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" \
       -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libvpx \
       -vsync 1 -async 1 -r 30 -threads 4 out.webm
   ```
2. After that, I've faced one more problem. If the user has a poor connection, WebRTC can dynamically change the video resolution. After the post-processing for such type of videos (with the different resolutions during the video) I see the frozen image until the end of the video and it started from the moment, where the resolution was dynamically changed. There are no error in the FFmpeg logs, just information about changing the resolution:

   ```
   [libvpx @ 0x559335713440] dimension change! 480x270 -> 320x180
   -async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000.
   ```

   After analyzing the logs, I realized that the problem was due to the STARTPTS parameter, which, after automatically changing the extension, became very large (equal to the number of frames that were before it). I tried to remove STARTPTS and leave only PTS.

   After that, the video started to work well, but only until the video resolution are dynamically changed, then again the audio and video tracks are out of sync.

   I've tried to scale videos to a static resolution before fixing timestamp and it helps. But it's a little bit extra work. Command example:

   ```
   ffmpeg -acodec libopus -vcodec libvpx \
       -i in.webm \
       -vf scale=640:480 \
       -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libvpx \
       -threads 4 out.webm
   ```

   Also I've tried to combine both commands using filter_complex, but it didn't work.

   I've worked with FFmpeg not so many time so far, so, maybe I'm doing something wrong? Maybe there are some easier ways to do that?

   Since Kurento uses GStreamer for the video recording, so maybe it would be a better option to reconfigure Kurento to fix timestamp during the video recording?

I can provide any videos and commands which I use.

I'm using:
Kurento Media Server 6.9.0, 
FFmpeg 4.1

Comment: Working with WebRTC files is painful. Provide a link to a file with the dimension change.

Comment: Here's an example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nFDiRYnmb9fDRIJVp8DPMTNi7Pt9F3Kh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @llogan, Sorry, I forgot to notify you. I left a link to video example above.

Comment: I was just randomly browsing and found this; just to note that since Kurento 6.16, the Recorder gained a [GapsFixMethod](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/client-javadoc/org/kurento/client/GapsFixMethod.html) property that, once set to `GENPTS`, should help avoiding lipsync issues (although it has other downsides, see the link).